# jQuery: selecting elements according to the beginning and the end of the name attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

I have this code:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').validate({

    //rules: { 'input_name': { email: true} },
    rules: { 'name^=input', 'name$=jander': { email: true} },
    messages: { 'input_name': "Jar" },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.insertBefore(element);
    },
    debug:true

    })

  });
  </script>

 </head> 

  <body>
<div id="jar">fasdf</div>

<form id="clar">
<p id="my_paragraph">Escribe ALGO para que haga la validacion de email</p>
<input name='input_jander' type="text" ">
<input type="submit" >

</form>
```

As you can see, I trying to apply the validation rule to all the input fields whose name attribute starts with "input" **and** ends with "jander", but it doesn't works (the error message is not showed)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those keys simply map to the `name` attribute of the form.

However, I've ran into this issue once before, and I solved it like so...

```
var rules = {},
    messages = {},
    inputs = $(':input[name^="input"]').filter(':input[name$="jander"]');

inputs.each(function() {
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
   rules[name] = { email: true };
   messages[name] = { email: 'Type a proper email, mate!' };
});

$('form').validate({
    'rules': rules,
    'messages': messages
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ve62k/) of `input` elements being matched.

Though you should probably come up with a saner identifier for those elements.

Answer (score 1):

just give the inputs you want to target a class and target them that way it'll be much easier. Why make it harder on yourself